# how to get selected option in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a select_tag from which I'm trying to get the selected option to add it to params and send to controller. My code is the following:

```
<% a=*(1..item.quantity) %>
<%= select_tag "quantity", options_for_select(a,1) %>
<%= button_to "Add to Cart", cart_path(item_id: item.id) %>
```

What's the best way to get the selected option and pass it as say, quantity, to cart_path?

Comment: What is is you're trying to do here? You have items as the basis of your options_for_select, but you want to calculate a quantity?

Comment: I'm tryint to give a user the ability to choose the quantity of an item that he wants to purchase. To do so, I have a select tag with multiple quantites, and I'm trying to get the quantity the user selects before he presses "Add to cart."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `form_tag`.

```
<%= form_tag(cart_path(item_id: item.id)) do -%>
  <%= select_tag "quantity", options_for_select((1..item.quantity).to_a,1) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Add to Cart" %>
<% end -%>
```

Now, you will get the value in `params[:quantity]`.

Comment: I'm getting an error: uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Cart. Just to clear things up, Cart is not a model.

Comment: @modsoussi show me the route of `cart` resource from your routes.rb file

Comment: `get 'cart' => 'sessions#show_cart',
post 'cart' => 'sessions#add_to_cart',
post 'delete_from_cart' => 'sessions#remove_from_cart'`

Comment: I have `<%= submit_tag("Add to cart") %>` instead of `<%= submit_tag Add to Cart %>` and that worked.